# Duda sobre la dirección IP de red y la dirección IP del broadcast de una red

Tags: redes, ip

Alguien podría explicarme esta duda que tengo:

- Si tengo una IP de clase A, por ejemplo la IP 10.X.X.X, la 10.0.0.0 no se coge por ser la IP de red y la 10.255.255.255 tampoco por ser la de broadcast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La convención de que la 0 se reserva para unicast, y la 255 para broadcast se reemplazó a mediados de los 90 por el uso de máscaras de red variables. Ahora  las IPv4 en cada extremo de la subred no cumplen ningún propósito y perfectamente se podrían asignar.

Aunque no hay impedimento técnico, en muchos casos se optó por el paradigma "gato del monasterio". O sea, mejor no tocar nada porque no se sabe si algo se romperá. Pero más concretamente, por que era menos trabajo seguir reciclando las mismas librerías de hace 40 años.